# Where to put data for an Erlang release to run

Tags: erlang, release, erlang-otp, rebar

I used rebar to create a release for my Erlang application.
My application need to read data from a file. Normally, it is located in the directory where I start erl.
But when it comes to release, I don't know where can I put the data so as the application can access it. I tried to put the file in both `rel/myrelease/bin` and `rel/myrelease/release/myverison` but the log always show:

> {{badmatch,{error,enoent}},

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the [application design principles documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id80836), normally you put application data into the application's `priv` directory, and your application code uses the [`code:priv_dir/1` function](http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#priv_dir-1) to locate its `priv` directory at runtime in order to find its data files.

Comment: Thanks Steve for pointing out. I was a kind of rush that forgetting even basic background.